# Dynamically allocated worker thread leaks after several minutes although it shouldn't

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Visual Studio 2010 SP1, 32-bit exe, Dell Core i7.

EDITED FOR CLARITY:

I am chasing a small memory leak in production code. It uses a lambda executed on a worker thread to dispatch events to a listener. Here is a distilled example of how the leak is caused. This sample leaks if you let it run long enough (several minutes). Can anyone tell me why? I'm sure I'll kick myself when it is pointed out. Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class Func>
static void __cdecl WorkerThreadProc(void* pData) {
    assert(pData != nullptr);
    Func* pFunc = static_cast<Func*>(pData);
    (*pFunc)();   // Execute the task.
    delete pFunc; // Clean up.
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class Func>
static void BeginThread(Func fn) {
    Func* pFn = new Func(fn);
    if (_beginthread(WorkerThreadProc<Func>, 0, pFn) == -1L) {
        errno_t err;
        _get_errno(&err);
        assert(false);        
        delete pFn; // Clean up.
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int, char**)
{
    printf_s("CTRL-C to quit:\n");
    while (true) {
        BeginThread( []()->void{} ); // Launch worker to execute task.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a `delete` with no matching `new`. Fair enough that only one is called because of the `assert(false)`, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @chris: I see a `new`, right at the beginning of `BeginThread`. He deletes the pointer either in the worker thread or if the thread fails, in `BeginThread`.

Comment: If your `main` function creates threads faster than the threads can execute and close, you will see what appears like a leak.

Comment: @Xeo, My bad, I didn't notice the failure condition.

Comment: @interjay I thought of that too, but the thread count stays steady at between 3 and 4 threads.

Comment: I edited the title to better reflect your actual question. That you're using a lambda is wholly uninteresting for the leak itself, I think. You could just aswell pass any other functor. Feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: The question has changed since this answer was written. I'm leaving the answer as-is, but note that it's no longer very relevant to the (now changed) question.

---

Don't know about any leak, but both the `new`-ing and the `void*` thing to lose type information, are completely *unnecessary*.

So, just remove that stuff.

No `new` = no leak.

Also, for those situations where `new` is warranted, do use smart pointers for cleanup.

That will also help prevent memory leaks (although not as guaranteed as just not doing `new`, to wit, you can have memory leaks in Java, to the great surprise of many Java programmers).

---

EDIT: I think [@interjay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564287/c11-lambda-as-function-arg-why-does-my-code-leak/12564789#comment16925007_12564287), “If your `main` function creates threads faster than the threads can execute and close, you will see what appears like a leak”, probably hit the nail on the head regarding the apparent memory leak.

Comment: How else can I ensure the threadproc has a valid object to work with if I don't clone the original and pass it into the threadproc? :(  The cloned object is deleted in the threadproc anyway, so no leak there.

Comment: @dripfeed: functions don't need to be cloned. they're valid as-is. you can just use a function. the problem of associating memory with your thread is not about the thread proc. to associate memory with the thread you can do essentially what you're doing except don't `new` thread proc, `new` the object that will represent the thread.

Comment: @Alf - thanks for your advice, but I'm confused. I am new'ing a lambda object which *is* the object that represents the thread. The threadproc then receives a clone of that lambda, executes it and deletes it. I could possibly code the solution without using lambdas (is that what you mean?) but I am chasing a small leak in production code and my sample represents the leak. I just don't know how it is caused.